# What does this RewriteRule do?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to migrate rewrite rules from apache to nginx. Can anybody explain what

```
RewriteRule ^api/.$ - [L]
```

does?

Comment: Seems that this is used to except all urls in api/ from further rewriting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment is correct.

Basically:

**[L]** means that this should be considered the **L**ast rule for anything matching this condition.

**-** when used as a target means "do nothing" or "accept as is".

**^api/.$** is your regex.  **^** means the beginning,  **$** means the end, and **.** means "any single character".

Comment: Thank you. Turns out in the subdirectory /api was a .htaccess file with further rules... This made me confused, as the rule in the question did apparently not behave as I would have expected. So this is kind of a passthrough that the .htaccess in the sub dir can rewrite the original request.